# How to rollback update in mysql after update trigger?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (Ubuntu). And I want to create a trigger that stops collisions between players and walls.

The players and walls table both have an x and y column.

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision AFTER UPDATE ON players BEGIN 
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'collision') FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y; 
END;
```

I want to know if this trigger will roll back the update if there is any rows that are actually selected, given my mysql version. Or do I have to manually do the rollback?

Also, there is a syntax problem with my trigger, and I'm not sure what it is..

Does anyone know?

EDIT:

I think I need the old syntax from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

I don't know how to complete the code though...

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT p.* FROM players p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT w.* FROM walls w WHERE w.x=p.x AND w.y=p.y);
COMMIT;
ROLLBACK;
```

EDIT2:

This is getting a syntax error:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision AFTER UPDATE ON players 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT count(*) FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y)>0 THEN 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Collision detected'; 
        END IF; 
    END;// 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

[According the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> There are limitations on what can appear in statements that a trigger executes when activated:
>
> - The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin
>   or end a transaction, such as START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK.
>   (ROLLBACK to SAVEPOINT is permitted because it does not end a
>   transaction.)
>
> MySQL handles errors during trigger execution as follows:
>
> - If a BEFORE trigger fails, the operation on the corresponding row is    not performed.
> - A BEFORE trigger is activated by the attempt to insert or modify the    row, regardless of whether the attempt subsequently succeeds.
> - An AFTER trigger is executed only if any BEFORE triggers and the row    operation execute successfully.
> - An error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure    of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.
> - For transactional tables, failure of a statement should cause    rollback of all changes performed by the statement. Failure of a
>   trigger causes the statement to fail, so trigger failure also causes
>   rollback. For nontransactional tables, such rollback cannot be done,
>   so although the statement fails, any changes performed prior to the
>   point of the error remain in effect